# How can I fill / populate DropDown with my IEnumerable<Model> value ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to set my dropdown list values from my model as it is the value I need to see in the dropdown
But I'm facing an error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

And here is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Language>
@using Web.Helpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}
<div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> </h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings","Language", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(WHATTOWRITEHERE, new SelectList(ViewBag.Languagess, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }

                }
            }           
        }               
    }               
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Settings()
{
   List<Language> activeL = LanguageController.GetAll();
   ViewBag.Languagess = activeLanguages;

   return View(activeL);
}
```

Maybe I could delete `ViewBag.Languagess` at all, so I can use  `(Model, "Id", "Name")` there instad of `(ViewBag.Languagess, "Id", "Name")`

Comment: I would try to avoid ViewBag at all costs if I were you. Strongly typed models are much easier to work with and less likely to break on you without causing a compiler warning.

Comment: Both are correct, but use only one of them. Pass data using either Viewbag or Model. I prefer Viewbag. And one more thing, make sure field names of your `Language` model are exactly as same as you write inside `new Selectlist()`

Comment: @mason can you provide me an example on my coode how that might be solved by avoiding view bags because I allready have strongly type Language there as you can see

Comment: @mason that is where I'm stucked at I don't know how to format properly @Html.DropDownListFor(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've requested how to do this with a strongly typed model instead of a ViewBag....

Right now your view requires a model of type `IEnumerable<Language>`. Change this to be a new class that holds all values your page needs.

```
public class LanguagesViewModel
{
    List<Language> ActiveLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var model = new LanguagesViewModel();
model.ActiveLanguages = activeLanguages;
return View(model);
```

Change your View to require a LanguagesViewModel:

```
@model LanguagesViewModel
```

Now you won't be working with the dynamic view bag.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageId, Model.ActiveLanguages, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I have one more question soon, my brain stopped totally, this is simple and nice solution, so can I leave you here in a comment soon new question if I decide to put it on a stackoverflow, I'm afraid I will be stucked again but we will see :)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Of course, if you have a new question, create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and feel free to ask a new question and let me know about it. I can't guarantee I'll answer but I'll at least look at it.

Comment: As of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App v8.0.3 (don't know when it started--this is just the version I'm using right now), DropDownListFor() takes a SelectList instead of a plain list, so the call needs to be changed from using Model.ActiveLanguages to new SelectList(@Model.ActiveLanguages, "Id", "Description"), swapping in the appropriate fields for Id and Description as applicable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Settings()
{
   List<Language> activeL = LanguageController.GetAll();

   ViewBag.Languages = activeLanguages.Select(item => new SelectListItem{
       Text = item.Name,
       Value = item.Id
    });

   return View(activeL);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageId, ViewBag.Languages, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write html like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(WHATEVER, new SelectList(ViewBag.languages, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And in your controller

```
public ActionResult Settings()
{
   List<Language> activeL = LanguageController.GetAll();
   ViewBag.Languagess = activeL;

   return View();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I thing your model could been an other type like Settings.

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

.cshtml

```
@model SettingsModel
@using Web.Helpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}
<div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> </h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings","Language", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LanguageId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Languagess, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }

                }
            }           
        }               
    }               
}
```

controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Language()
    {
        List<Language> activeL = LanguageController.GetAll();
        ViewBag.Languagess = activeLanguages;
        return View();
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Language(SettingsModel settings)
    {
        Language selectedLanguage = LanguageController.GetAll().Where(l => l.Id == settings.LanguageId).SingleOrDefault();
        //...   your post operations.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**model**

```
   public class LanguageViewModel
    {
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Language> ActiveLanguages{get; set;}
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Language()
    {
       var languageViewModel = new LanguageViewModel
        {
          ActiveLanguages = LanguageController.GetAll();
        }
         return View(languageViewModel);
     }
```

**View**

```
@model LanguageViewModel
@using Web.Helpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}
<div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> </h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings","Language", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LanguageId, new SelectList(Model.ActiveLanguages, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    }

                }
            }           
        }               
    }               
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It would work like in this example:

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "Exemplo1",
          Value = "Exemplo1"
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Exemplo2",
            Value = "Exemplo2",
            Selected = true
        });
   listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Exemplo3",
            Value = "Exemplo3"
        });
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tipo, listItems, "-- Select Status --")
```